# Thin missing css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I'm debugging a Bitnami Rails implementation.  I'd like to run Thin instead of Apache to see if my error still shows up.

I go to the Rails app directory using SSH and run this command:

```
$ thin -e production start
```

And Thin starts up on 3000.  But, when I access using a browser, it looks like none of the CSS is getting used.

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Thanks!

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Rails does not serve static assets in production.

Usually there is a line

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

in `config/production.rb`.

Setting it to `true` will overwrite the default. If there is no such line, it should be added

If the problems persist, please provide your rails version, and whether you use asset pipeline.

Comment: Is there some way to override that?

Comment: I've updated the answer. By setting `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `config/production.rb`.

Comment: Thank You!!  I've been having a problem with a Bitnami Rails stack.  I'm using Apache and getting a PUT 501 error whenever I use jquery ajax.  By running the same app with just Thin, it works fine.  So, now I know it's an Apache setting issue.

Comment: Just a currious newbie - Would it be wrong to run the production app just using Thin?  If not, I'm going to try Ngenx.

Comment: It's a big question. It depends much on your app traffic and server performance. I am not an expert, I suppose running thin directly may be OK for low traffic app, but for commercial application you'd better do a thorough testing first. In general, it is usually advised to put Rails server behind load balancer like ngnix, and not to serve static assets via rails too.